# How can I filter several fields in one filter?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Is possible to create search filter to search from not one field, but from `CONCAT(name, description)` ?

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper->add('search');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution with doctrine_orm_callback type

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{


    $datagridMapper
        ->add( 'text', 'doctrine_orm_callback', array(
            'callback' => array($this, 'getSearchFilter'),
            'field_type' => 'text'
        ) );
}

public function getSearchFilter($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
    if (!$value['value']) {
        return;
    }

    $exp = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr();
    $queryBuilder->andWhere($exp->like($exp->concat($alias.'.name', $alias.'.description'), $exp->literal('%' . $value['value'] . '%')));

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Great solution by @Liutas!

If you only want to use your *concat* as a workaround to search multiple fields you can use this code:

```
public function getFullTextFilter($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value)
{
    if (!$value['value']) {
        return;
    }

    $queryBuilder->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->like($alias.'.name', $queryBuilder->expr()->literal('%' . $value['value'] . '%')),
        $queryBuilder->expr()->like($alias.'.description', $queryBuilder->expr()->literal('%' . $value['value'] . '%')),
        $queryBuilder->expr()->like($alias.'.anotherfield', $queryBuilder->expr()->literal('%' . $value['value'] . '%'))
    ));

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @webDEVILopers ' answer, here is a generic class that can be used on any field :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQueryInterface;
use Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Filter\BooleanFilter;

class MultiStringFilter extends BooleanFilter
{
    /**
     * @param string $field should be in the form field1-field2-…-fieldn
     */
    public function filter(ProxyQueryInterface $queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $data)
    {
        $fields = explode('-', $field);
        $filterActive = $data['value'];
        if ($filterActive === null) {
            return;
        }

        $subConditions = [];
        foreach ($fields as $field) {

            $subConditions[] = $queryBuilder->expr()->like(
                "LOWER($alias.$field)",
                $queryBuilder->expr()->literal('%' . strtolower($data['value']) . '%')
            );
        }

        if (count($subConditions) > 1) {
            $queryBuilder->andWhere(new Expr\Orx($subConditions));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfect but breaks the page listing when no filters selected, adding the following fixed it

`if(count($subConditions) > 1)
        $queryBuilder->andWhere(new Expr\Orx($subConditions));`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it!